# Redeclaring finentry results in dot printed at the beginning of the document

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

As a follow-up of my [old question "How to print the internal ID of the bibliography entries in the output format for referring to files?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/548416/98645) I now decided not to use the internal ID, but the special field just as [@moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe) suggested me, that is declared by default.

So this is an example document:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{file}{\texttt{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\newunit\newblock\printfield{file}\finentrypunct}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, just by changing the to be printed field `entrykey` [from the original answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/548419/98645) to `file`, strange extra dots appear.

[image]

When you actually use the file field, you can notice they appear in front of the bibliography entries that follow on entries that *do not* have a file entry set. (Also, as you can see in the example above, the first entry seems to be excluded.)

Even when you remove `\finentrypunct` (which I don't want, but did for debugging), they are still there.
So I have no idea where this dot **in front** of the entries comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a typo in the other answer. The entry should not end with `\finentrypunct` but with `\finentry`:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{file}{\texttt{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\newunit\newblock\printfield{file}\finentry}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, seems to work!